# Can dism be run with all features on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, dism

I've tried running dism from folder `C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\x86\DISM` on Windows 7 SP1 (32 bit).

I still get limited command options and error 87. I want to use the RestoreHealth switch for online system. Is there any way to do this on Windows 7?

Comment: is the question now answered?

Answer (score 5):

The [/RestoreHealth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824869.aspx) option is only available since Windows 8. For Windows 7, Microsoft backported the `/ScanHealth` option which does the same like RestoreHealth with the update [KB2966583](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2966583).

Comment: The question is answered as far as I know. The windows 8.1 deployment tools will run on windows 7 but not with all options, even when run from the windows kits 8.1 directory. (at least that's what happens on my win7 system anyhow).

Comment: DISM uses the servicing stack file from WinSxS from the image, so the WIn7 stack which doesn't support it. if the question is [answered, mark it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: This answer makes no sense. You say `/ScanHealth` does the same as RestoreHealth, which contradicts what you say in the comment above, furthermore it's plainly wrong - `/RestoreHealth` is supposed to restore or repair missing or damaged system files from an image, whereas `/ScanHealth` (at least on W7) only scans the SUR for errors (which coincidentally, fails at what it supposedly is said to fix, i.e. the SFC store).

Comment: next time don't troll around. In win8/10 scan and repair are different, but for win7, scan does the same like repair for 8/10 * facepalm*